# Xcode 6.3.1: iOS app runs but won't archive

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks

On Xcode 6.3.1 using a multi-project workspace - two Swift frameworks, the app itself, and Cocoapods. I can **successfully build and run** the app both on the simulator as well as my iPhones, but when I try to Archive it, I get:

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

This error appears to happen on two of my view controller files, but I have no idea what is wrong with them. Tried building from command line. Fruitless. I've also messed with my build settings, as has been suggested in other questions, to no avail.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Can't submit anything to app store or make a test IPA :( Here is the stack trace produced:

```
    0  swift                    0x0000000109d14a18 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
    1  swift                    0x0000000109d14ef4 SignalHandler(int) + 452
    2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8fbb0f1a _sigtramp + 26
    3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 1883566336
    4  swift                    0x00000001097f0d85 (anonymous namespace)::EmitDFDiagnostics::run() + 469
    5  swift                    0x00000001097fa55e swift::SILPassManager::runFunctionPasses(llvm::ArrayRef<swift::SILFunctionTransform*>) + 1310
    6  swift                    0x00000001097fb6a7 swift::SILPassManager::runOneIteration() + 2359
    7  swift                    0x00000001097fbe1c swift::SILPassManager::run() + 1212
    8  swift                    0x00000001097f8725 swift::runSILDiagnosticPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 597
    9  swift                    0x00000001095fdd6f frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 4319
    10 swift                    0x00000001095fcae6 main + 1814
    11 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff8ff895c9 start + 1
```

Comment: [File a radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) so Apple can look into the issue.

Comment: I have already filed one. They haven't replied yet. This is mostly a litmus test wanting to see if other people are having the same issues and if so if there's something I can change/tweak as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I discovered the thing that was keeping the app from successfully archiving was the fact that i used the find() function to find the index of an item in an array. That function is provided by Swift, but when used in my actual codebase it wouldn't archive. I'm assuming there may be a couple stock functions that are preventing archiving. And keep in mind, these functions build and can run on the simulator, but they will not archive.